# Surah Al-Kahf 18:9-22: What is this story about youths in a cave?

Tags: surat-al-kahf

I have been reading Surah al-Kahf and I find myself quite confused about ayat 9-22. What is this story about youths in a cave? It is presented like it should be a story that I am already familiar with, but I am not. Especially in ayah 22 where it gets into a discussion about how many youths there were and whether or not the dog counted among their number.
Could someone help lend some background and context to this?

Comment: You should read some good tafsir like tafseer ibn e kaseer.  here is a link,  read from there. 
http://www.quranwebsite.com/tafsir%20ibn%20kathir/ibn_018_al_khaif.html

Comment: here is another link of same tafseer in different format, with arabic etc... http://www.quran4u.com/Tafsir%20Ibn%20Kathir/018%20Kahf.htm#أَمْ

Comment: Thank you for those. From this it sounds like the story of the youths in the cave is something from the Rabbinic tradition or in Torah somewhere?

Comment: Actually as muslims we believe that torah anjeel zaboor and quran are all from Allah, there were also other books but those are not known today. Allah sent many messengers and many books. All of those messengers and books are right. And we idealize them. But as last prophet, we follow Muhammad peace be upon him and last book quran, which is perfectly preserved. And all other books are not preserved and have been altered, so cannot be trusted. So, you will occasionally find many stories of old people and other things common, but we go with preserved quran's version.

Comment: Oh ok now that makes sense to me. Thank you for your time and patience as I am still learning. Jazakallah.

Comment: That's an honor for me to help anyone learn. Best of luck. May Allah guide us all to the right path.

Comment: There is a religious-historical series about the men of the Cave made in Iran. It's translated into English. Maybe you like to watch it. http://www.ifilm.ir/English/Serie/81/#.Vs4uQdDZxm0

Comment: Thank you, I'll be sure to take a look at this. Actually I was just listening to Ust Nouman Ali Khan lecture today and he was discussing this same story. One interesting thing he talks about is all the discussion of how many people were in the cave and such was an example of focusing on and asking the wrong questions. http://www.muslimcentral.com/nouman-ali-khan-story-musa-khidr-1-6/

Comment: Would you mind presenting that as an answer here @ZiaUlRehmanMughal

Comment: Ok i will try...

Comment: BTW @Noor most of the muslims scholars discourage any movie etc on the quranic stories or on prophets of islam especially. Most say its haraam, explaining why is a big topic. But at least we should avoid them. For details read this ruling here https://islamqa.info/en/158232

Comment: According to Christians ahl-al Kahf have been Christian believers who fled from the Authorities (non-Believers apparently Romans) and searched for rescue in a cave see also https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Seven_Sleepers and Goethe wrote a poem in German about them based on both christian and Muslim texts http://www.wissen-im-netz.info/literatur/goethe/diwan/12.htm#Siebenschl%C3%A4fer in his West-östlicher Divan!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### All perfect praise be to Allah

(Question was answered previously in comments, i am writing this answer on request of a member.)

Before coming to the story of the cave, **here is some background.**

Actually **as muslims we believe that torah anjeel zaboor and quran are all from Allah**, there were also other books but those are not known today. Allah sent many messengers and many books.
All of those messengers and books are right. And we idealize them. And we believe those books were revealed for either a community only or some were for the whole world but for short time, not forever.

> And We have revealed to you, [O Muhammad], the Book in truth,
>   confirming that which preceded it of the Scripture and as a criterion
>   over it. Quran 5/47

As last prophet, we follow Muhammad peace be upon him and last book quran, which we believe is the last book revealed by Allah and is continuity of previus scriptures, which is for whole humanity and is the last book to be followed til the end day, which is perfectly preserved. And all other books are not preserved and have been altered, so cannot be trusted, some books vanished completely. 
**Now coming to the main question, about the story of cave**
You will occasionally find many stories of old people and other things common in books like bible torah and quran, but we go with preserved quran's version. And we suspect the versions of bible and torah might had been altered.
For details on these ayahs and the tafsir you can lookup any good tafseer, i will recommend tafsir ibn kaseer.
Google yourself or Read [here](http://www.quranwebsite.com/tafsir%20ibn%20kathir/ibn_018_al_khaif.html) or [here](http://www.quran4u.com/Tafsir%20Ibn%20Kathir/018%20Kahf.htm#).

And as you have found the reason yourself **why the number of people is discussed**, it is true that it is for the people who ask useless questions. Like the people who were ordered to take meat of a cow and they kept questioning and questioning issa(Jesus) and it got harder and harder for them to get meat of that specific cow. you can read that story [here](http://quran.com/2/67-71).

### Allah knows best.